# Derive extra column from Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe, how to add an extra column which is derived from the columns in the dataframe i.e.

```
data = {'date': ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-02'],
        'number': [10, 21, 20],
        'location': ['CA', 'NY', 'NJ']
        }

print pd.DataFrame(data)

  location  number        date
0       CA      10  2016-01-01
1       NY      21  2016-01-01
2       NJ      20  2016-01-02
```

I want to generate an extra column from `location` and `date` i.e.get date and then generate key values for `extra_column` where key is `date + i` and value is some random string. Where `i = random.randint(1,3)`

```
  location  number       date     extra_column
0       CA      10  2016-01-01    {{2016-01-01, CA}, {2016-01-02, something}, {2016-01-03, something else}}
1       NY      21  2016-01-01    {{2016-01-01, NY}, {2016-01-02, someplace}}
2       NJ      20  2016-01-02    {{2016-01-02, NJ}, {2016-01-03, anything}}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you expect there to be in your `extra_column` exactly? A string? Why do you say key values?

Comment: As a sidenote, your data dict's "number" key as too many elements. You should delete the last two ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function do to the manipulation with the current columns and just add the column to the `DataFrame`. See the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-02'],
        'number': [10, 21, 20],
        'location': ['CA', 'NY', 'NJ']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def somefunc(date, location):
    # some code to generate extra column


date_vals = df['date'].values
loc_vals = df['location'].values

new_col_vals = somefunc(date_vals, loc_vals)

# add the column by doing the following
df['new_col'] = new_col_vals
```

Hope it helps.